# Why can graphene nanoribbons be safely used as electrdes, despite having a finite band gap?

Tags: band-structure, siesta, electronic-transport, graphene, nanostructures

I was following the following [this](http://dipc.ehu.es/frederiksen/tstutorial/index.php/Zig-zag_graphene_nanoribbon) tutorial.

As far as my understanding goes, one should use bulk-like metallic electrodes to avoid problems with screening and Fermi-level definition.

**Can someone explain why GNRs (graphene nanoribbons) can be safely used as electrodes, since they would have a finite band gap?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the tutorial it is obvious that the GNR used is metallic, i.e. has no band-gap.

Please see the transmission functions at the end: http://dipc.ehu.es/frederiksen/tstutorial/index.php/Nanoribbon_answers

But you are absolutely correct. DFT calculations with gapped materials are likely to give wrong answers:

1. because the fermi-level is ill-defined
2. because the screening length of semi-conductors/insulators are excessively long. One *could* mitigate this by having a device that is longer than the screening length, but that turns out to be unfeasible in DFT :)

Comment: Thanks Nick! So if I understand correctly, one should check if the GNR used as the electrode is metallic.
If not, how could someone use a pristine 2D graphene electrode while keeping a GNR as screening region?

Comment: I don't understand your question? Graphene is a *metal* (in terms of NEGF) since it has no band-gap, i.e. a well-defined fermi-level.

Comment: Indeed, my question was related to GNR in particular. Quantum confining graphene should open the band gap (even if small), so it could be tricky to use them as electrodes, right?

Comment: Bottomline, if your electrode is metallic, it can be used, if not, it should not be used.

Comment: Reminder about the SIESTA chatroom in case more space is required for comments/chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136776/siesta